# How many palindromes can you create from array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a basic code that is taking an int array and outputing all of its optional palindromes.
Example: {1, 2, 2, 2, 3}
Output: {2 2}, {2 1 2}, {2 3 2}, {2 2 2}

I was thinking of reorganizing the array in every way possible and checking if it's an array by each time. But, I think I'm heading to it wrongly.

The code I made for now is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 };// 7 int //56
    
    bool check = true;
    for(int i=0; i< sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)/2;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)-1-i])
            check = false;
    }
    if(check)
    {
        for(int i=0; i< sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i]<< " ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I will appreciate help if possible. Thank you all and have an amazing day!

Comment: Please don't tag spam. C and C++ and C# are all different languages. They're not the same just because they all start with `c`, any more than a cat, a car and a carrot are the same. Tags have relevance and meaning here. Please don't abuse them - use only tags that are actually relevant to your post.

Comment: Since the question is about how many palindromes can be created, there's no need to actually generate them. You just need to calculate the number of combinations that will result in a palindrome. That boils down to a math problem.

Comment: @Mayli Similar logic is likely applicable in many languages, however you have chosen to use syntax and codes that are specific to C++, not C (`cout` and `operator<<`)

Comment: This question's code/phrasing very likely came from one of many countless coding challenge/puzzle websites. They take advantage of people who want to learn C++ by offering arcane coding puzzles, promising that you don't need to study and learn C++ with a good textbook, just do one puzzle after another. Everyone eventually realizes that these useless coding puzzles are a waste of time, and there's nothing to be learned from them. But only after wasting a lot of time doing them. And there's nothing to show for it.

Comment: I will still really appreciate help if possible solving it

Comment: In case you do want to shuffle every permutations of the array, you can use [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), however that is not a good way to solve this

Comment: @Ranoiaetep what do u think will he a good way of solving  it

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if any suggestions on a good way have already been mentioned in the comments... Do you understand the mathematics of _combinations_? If you know how many of each value you have available, then you can generate the number of combinations that use any number of combinations of those sets of values. The special case is that a maximum of one set of values can contain an odd number for any single combination that results in a palindrome. When I say "set of values", I mean a set of values that are the same. For instance, you have three possible sets of 2: `{2}`, `{2,2}`, and `{2,2,2}`.

Comment: @paddy i do understand the logic u suggested but i dont know how to transform it into code

Comment: The trick is to work it out on paper first. Figure out exactly how you need to split up and group your data in order to do these calculations. Think about all palindromes of length 1, length 2, length 3, etc. If you can't do it conceptually on paper, there's no way you can translate it into code.

Answer (score 0):

We have to implement 2 major mathematical concepts here

1. Create a power set
2. Get all permutations from powerset.

Then, of course check for the palindrome property.

Let's start with the power set.

We will first make a simplification for an easier understanding of the task. We will use lower case letters in this example. Then we will take 4 elements `{A,B,C,D}` for demo purposes.

What we need to generate is a power set from this. There are 2 main standard approaches.

1. Counting with checking of set bits via it mask
2. Setting more and more bits in a field and do permutations.

Let us look at solution 1. Counting. Based on "abcd" we will get

```
Count Binary Selection (sub set)
              DCBA   Cardinality
0     0000   {----}     0                Empty set
1     0001   {---A}     1
2     0010   {--B-}     1
3     0011   {--BA}     2
4     0100   {-C--}     1
5     0101   {-C-A}     2
6     0110   {-CB-}     2
7     0111   {-CBA}     3     
8     1000   {D---}     4
9     1001   {D--A}     2
10    1010   {D-B-}     2
11    1011   {D-BA}     3
12    1100   {DC--}     3
13    1101   {DC-A}     3
14    1110   {DCB-}     3
15    1111   {DCBA}     4

As a result we will get the powerset:
{{A},{B},{AB},{C},{AC},{BC},{ABC},{D},{AD},{BD},{ABD},{CD},{ACD},{BCD},{ABCD}}
```

If you look at the output, we see that the elements are not sorted according to their cardinality. Therefore we will choose a different approach. We will set more and more bits in a field an do permutations on them. Also with a selector. Then, we will get something like this:

```
Binary  Selection
0000      {----}                    Empty set. Ignored
0001      {---A}                    Set bit 0
0010      {--B-}                    Permutation
0101      {-C--}                    Permutation
1000      {D---}                    Permutation
0011      {--BA}                    Set next bit number 1
0101      {-C-A}                    Permutation      
1001      {D--A}                    Permutation      
0110      {-CB-}                    Permutation      
1010      {D-B-}                    Permutation      
1100      {D--A}                    Permutation      
0111      {-CBA}                    Set next bit number 2
1011      {D-BA}                    Permutation      
1101      {DC-A}                    Permutation      
1110      {DCB-}                    Permutation      
1111      {DCBA}                    Set next bit number 3

As a result we will get the "more reasonable/expected" powerset:
{{A},{B},{C},{D},{AB},{AC},{AD},{BC},{BD},{AD},{ABC},{ABD},{ACD},{BCD},{ABCD}}
```

By the way. The overall number of sub sets is of course `2^n` and the size of the cardinality group is equal to the corresponding binomial coeeficient.

```
Cardinality
0    4 choose 0  --> 1   
1    4 choose 1  --> 4
2    4 choose 1  --> 6
3    4 choose 1  --> 4
4    4 choose 1  --> 1

               Sum: 16
```

The corresponding algorithm is easy to implement, which can also be seen later in the code example.

---

Next, after having calculated one subset, we will create all permutations of data in this subset with the existing C++ function `std::next_permutation`.

After a successful check for a Palindrome, we will add this subset to a resulting `std::set` . We will use the `std::set` to avoid duplicates.

At the end, we can show the result.

The below example is brute force and hence very very slow for big input arrays.

Anyway, please see the example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::vector testData{ 1,2,2,2,3 };

    // Here we will store the result
    std::set<std::vector<int>> result{};

    // Selectors for creating the subsets of the power set
    std::vector<bool> selector(testData.size());

    // For all number of elements in the original test data
    for (size_t k{0}; k < testData.size(); ++k) {

        // Set selector bits. In each loop one more bit. So, 1 then 11, then 111 and so on
        selector[k] = true;

        // Do all permutations of the above set selector bits
        do {
            // Build the subset
            std::vector<int> subset{};
            for (std::size_t n{}; n < testData.size(); ++n)
                if (selector[n]) subset.push_back(testData[n]);

            do {

                // Check, if palindrome
                if (subset == std::vector<int>(subset.rbegin(), subset.rend()))
                    result.insert(subset);

            } while (std::next_permutation(subset.begin(), subset.end()));

        } while (std::prev_permutation(selector.begin(), selector.end()));
    }
    // Show all resulting palindromes
    std::cout << "\n\nNumber of palindromes:  " << result.size() << "\n\n";
    int counter{ 1 };
    for (const std::vector<int>& v : result) {
        std::cout << "Palindrome " << counter++ << ":\t";
        for (const int i : v) std::cout << ' ' << i;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```